# Show that a definite integral is non negative.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the definite integral
$$I=AB+CD$$ where
$$ A=\int_{1}^{100}\sinh\left(\frac{\ln x}{8}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\ln x}{2}\right)dx $$
$$ B=\int_{1}^{100}\cosh\left(\frac{\ln x}{8}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\ln x}{2}\right)dx $$
$$ C=\int_{1}^{100}\cosh\left(\frac{\ln x}{8}\right)\sin \left(\frac{\ln x}{2}\right)dx $$
$$ D=\int_{1}^{100}\sinh\left(\frac{\ln x}{8}\right)\sin \left(\frac{\ln x}{2}\right)dx $$
Here $\sinh(\theta)$, $\cosh(\theta)$ are hyperbolic functions.

> **Question** Prove that $I\geq 0$.

My try: We observe that for $x\geq 1$, $$\sinh\left (\frac{\ln x}{8}\right)=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{8}}-x^{\frac{-1}{8}}}{2}\geq 0$$
and $$\cosh\left (\frac{\ln x}{8}\right)=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{8}}+x^{\frac{-1}{8}}}{2}\geq 0$$
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thank you. But I am not able to get that how to conclude from this? Please post a short answer. I would accept your answer.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Please reply. Thank you